# How to set width of sidebar in google chrome experimental API

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How can i change the width of sidebar. I was unable to find any methods in documentation and source code. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `width` of `<html>` of the HTML file maybe? (This is how I change the size of a popup)
The experimental APIs are still developing so it may change later.